# How to check if an element has been unselected using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to check if an element has been unselected in a form;
So I can check if the input is valid, but i'm stuck at the selected part;
I've tried to add onclick() functions but as the div containing my form is selected too when I click on an input field, it's not working.
Any ideas ?

this is what I have for a form click :

```js
document.getElementById("contactForm").onclick = function ()
{
  if (messageClicked==1){
    console.log(document.getElementById("formMessage").value);
  }
  
}
```

and for an input :

```js
document.getElementById("formMessage").onclick = function ()
{
  messageClicked=1;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [`blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)?

Comment: have you even heard [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required) attribute ?, this will prevent from submitting form if user has not selected it. see example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required#example)

Comment: @bogdanoff it's also a great answer but i'd like to use my own CSS for it so user19642323's answer better suits me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is indeed the [blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) !
Thanks [user19642323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19642323/user19642323) !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @GouthamJ.M just have to click on the button to get the documentation about the answer ^^

Comment: Yes , you can but it is better to not redirect user to other sites , you could provide a clear answer in stack overflow